# Asterisk PBX - Infinite Loop when user disconnects while using 'Read' application from LUA

Tags: lua, asterisk, pbx

I'm configuring interactive dial plans for asterisk at the moment and because I already know some LUA I thought it'd be easier to go that route.

I have a start extension like this:

```lua
["h"] = function(c,e)
    app.verbose("Hung Up")
  end;

["s"] = function(c, e)
    local d = 0
    while d == 0 do
      say:hello()
      app.read("read_result", nil, 1)

      d = channel["read_result"].value;

      if d == 1 then
        say:goodbye()
      elseif d == 2 then
        call:forward('front desk')
      end

      d = 0
    end

    say:goodbye()
end;
```

As you can see, I want to repeat the instructions `say:hello()` whenever
the user gives an invalid answer. However, if the user hangs up while
`app.read` waits for their answer, asterisk ends up in an infinite loop
since `d` will always be `nil`.

I WOULD check for `d==nil` to detect disconnection, but `nil` also shows
up when the user just presses the `#` pound sign during `app.read`.

So far I've taken to using `for` loops instead of `while` to limit the
maximum iterations that way, but I'd rather find out how to detect a disconnected
channel. I can't find any documentation on that though.

I also tried setting up a `h` extension, but the program won't go to it when the
user hangs up.

Asterisk Verbose Output:

```
[...]
-- Executing [s@test-call:1] read("PJSIP/2300-00000004", "read_result,,1")                │        test.lua:3: in main chunk
-- Accepting a maximum of 1 digit.                                                       │        [C]: ?
-- User disconnected                                                                      │root@cirro asterisk lua test.lua
-- Executing [s@test-call:1] read("PJSIP/2300-00000004", "read_result,,1")                │Global B
-- Accepting a maximum of 1 digit.                                                       │LocalB-B->a
-- User disconnected                                                                      │LocalB-A
-- Executing [s@test-call:1] read("PJSIP/2300-00000004", "read_result,,1")                │LocalB-A
-- Accepting a maximum of 1 digit.                                                       │LocalB-A
-- User disconnected                                                                      │root@cirro asterisk cp ~/test.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing
-- Executing [s@test-call:1] read("PJSIP/2300-00000004", "read_result,,1")
[...]
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can see in app_read docs(and any other doc), that it return different values for incorrect execution(when channel is down).

Also this exact app offer simplified way of determine result:

```
core show application Read

  -= Info about application 'Read' =- 

[Synopsis]
Read a variable. 

[Description]
Reads a #-terminated string of digits a certain number of times from the user
in to the given <variable>.
This application sets the following channel variable upon completion:
${READSTATUS}: This is the status of the read operation.
    OK
    ERROR
    HANGUP
    INTERRUPTED
    SKIPPED
    TIMEOUT
```

If that still not suite you, you can direct ask asterisk about CHANNEL(state)

**PS** You **NEVER** should write dialplan or any other program with infinite loop. Count your loops and exit at 10+. This will save **ALOT** of money for client.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed - i hadn't actually realised that AMI has such an extensive built-in documentation.